# Which files or folders should be in .gitignore in Quartus Prime 18.1 Lite (Verilog) project?

Tags: git, gitignore, quartus

I wish to know which files, extensions and/or folders are cache data that are generated again every time that I compile the project!

Comment: create a git repo before generation, then do 'git status' after generation. You will see all generated files.

Comment: Thanks @Serge Thats a really good ideia! So, just for clarify, you mean: 
-1) Create a project;
-2) Add all files of project ( 'git add');
-3) Compile the project;
-4) See witch files are generated by compilation with 'git status';
-5) And them add all these files to `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.settings,
.classpath,
target,
.project,
bin